# Who is the guy that Shirou passes in the Clock Tower that he mentions he recognizes?

Tags: fate-stay-night

[image: Who is this man?]

In the Epilogue episode of UBW, who is the guy that Shirou passes in the Clock Tower that he mentions he recognizes? Is his appearance significant in anyway? Like Luvia's or Waver's appearance (as El-Melloi II)?

Comment: the only other person he could be is Mikiya Kokutou but while Kokutou has a better reason for being at the Clock Tower (to see his sister if she went her seperate ways with Touko), kinda similar to Shirou in tersm of putting himself in harms way even when not fully understanding what he is up agains and has the same kind of hair as Twice along with classes, Kokutou's eyes are blue and with the current image it appears they are brown

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be [Twice H. Pieceman](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Twice_H._Pieceman) or someone that looks like him at least.

[image: Twice!]

As for why they decided to show him... I'm not sure, but...

It would seem that he and Shiro (or rather EMIYA) shares some common viewpoints about war (orphaned by conflict), but ultimatly came to different conclusions on what to do.

[image: Extra]
[image: More Extra]

Comment: Man, Nasu's sense for naming white people sure is something. "Waver Velvet"; "Bazett Fraga McRemitz"; whatever the heck Sola-Ui's full name is; and now "Twice H. Pieceman". (Some dude on reddit suggested that this was, for whatever reason, Tohno Shiki, but this Pieceman fellow seems like a much closer match.)

Comment: @senshin True, but I can't help but think that Twice is actually a pretty decent sounding name.  I kind of wish I had a friend named Twice.

Comment: @senshin [Sola-Ui Nuada-Re Sophia-Ri](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sola-Ui_Nuada-Re_Sophia-Ri). I think that one takes the cake.